# Background PHP Processes

Tags: php, process

I am developing a website that requires a lot background processes for the site to run. For example, a queue, a video encoder and a few other types of background processes. Currently I have these running as a PHP cli script that contains:

```
while (true) {

    // some code

    sleep($someAmountOfSeconds);

}
```

Ok these work fine and everything but I was thinking of setting these up as a deamon which will give them an actual process id that I can monitor, also I can run them int he background and not have a terminal open all the time.

I would like to know if there is a better way of handling these? I was also thinking about cron jobs but some of these processes need to loop every few seconds.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Creating a daemon which you can make calls to and ask questions would seem the sensible option. Depends on wether your hoster permits such things, especially if you're requiring it to do work every few seconds, then definately an OS based service/daemon would seem far more sensible than anything else.

Comment: Yeah, I have a few dedicated boxes for this project so I can run anything I want really.

Comment: Then a service/daemon is most certainly the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a daemon in PHP, but in my experience this is a lot of hard work and the result is unreliable due to PHP's memory management and error handling.

I had the same problem, I wanted to write my logic in PHP but have it daemonised by a stable program that could restart the PHP script if it failed and so I wrote [The Fat Controller](http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/).

It's written in C, runs as a daemon and can run PHP scripts, or indeed anything.   If the PHP script ends for whatever reason, The Fat Controller will restart it.   This means you don't have to take care of daemonising or error recovery - it's all handled for you.

The Fat Controller can also do lots of other things such as parallel processing which is ideal for queue processing, you can read about some potential use cases here:

http://fat-controller.sourceforge.net/use-cases.html

Answer (score 1):

I've done this for 5 years using PHP to run background tasks and its no different to doing in any other language. Just use CRON and lock files. The lock file will prevent multiple instances of your script running.

Also its important to monitor your code and one check I always do to prevent stale lock files from preventing scripts to run is to have second CRON job to check if if the lock file is older than a few minutes and if an instance of the PHP script is running, if not it then removes the lock file.

Using this technique allows you to set your CRON to run the script every minute without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [System::Daemon](http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/) module from PEAR.

Answer (score 0):

One solution (that I really need to try myself, as I may need it) is to use cron, but get the process to loop for five mins or so. Then, get cron to kick it off every five minutes. As one dies, the next one should be finishing (or close to finishing).

Bear in mind that the two may overlap a bit, and so you need to ensure that this doesn't cause a clash (e.g. writing to the same video file). Some simple inter-process communication may be useful, even if it is just writing to a PID file in the temp directory.

This approach is a bit low-tech but helps avoid PHP hanging onto memory over the longer term - sort of in-built task restarts!